# How to add the value of a row to other rows based on some criteria in R?

Tags: r, group-by, tidyverse, dplyr

I have a panel data for costs, sampled monthly for various product types. I also have "Generic" costs which doesn't belong to any product type. A super simple representative `df` looks like this:

```
type <- c("A","A","B","B","C","C","Generic","Generic")
year <- c(2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020)
month <- c(1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2)
cost <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,600,630)
volume <- c(10,11,20,21,30,31,60,63)
df <- data.frame(type,year,month,cost,volume)
```

```
type      year  month  cost  volume
 A        2020  1      1     10
 A        2020  2      2     11
 B        2020  1      3     20
 B        2020  2      4     21
 C        2020  1      5     30 
 C        2020  2      6     31
 Generic  2020  1      600   60
 Generic  2020  2      630   63
```

I need to distribute the "Generic" costs to product types according to their "Volume".

For example,

For 2020-1, the volume ratio of

- product type A: 10 / (10 + 20 + 30) = 1/6
- product type B: 20 / (10 + 20 + 30) = 2/6
- product type C: 30 / (10 + 20 + 30) = 3/6

For 2020-2, the volume ratio of

- product type A: 11 / (11 + 21 + 31) = 11/63
- product type B: 21 / (11 + 21 + 31) = 21/63
- product type C: 31 / (11 + 21 + 31) = 31/63

So, I would like to distribute "Generic" costs for 2020-1 to product types like this:

- 1/6 * 600 = 100 for product type A
- 2/6 * 600 = 200 for product type B
- 3/6 * 600 = 300 for product type C

Similarly for 2020-2, I would like to distribute "Generic" costs like:

- 11/63 * 630 = 110 for product type A
- 21/63 * 630 = 210 for product type B
- 31/63 * 630 = 310 for product type C

In the end, I would like to end up with the following data frame:

```
type      year  month  new_cost  volume
 A        2020  1      101       10
 A        2020  2      112       11
 B        2020  1      203       20
 B        2020  2      214       21
 C        2020  1      305       30 
 C        2020  2      316       31
```

I already have the total volume in the original dataframe within the "Generic" type, so there is no need to calculate that seperately.

I was trying to do these calculations via `dplyr` package's `group_by()` and `mutate()` functions, but I couldn't figure out how.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

We can do this using data.table, by first merging in the generic costs separately and spreading them according to the percentage of volume made up by each type in each month/year:

```
df <- setDT(df)
generic <- df[type == "Generic"]
setnames(generic, "cost", "generic_cost")
df <- df[type !="Generic"]
df[, volume_ratio:=volume/sum(volume), by = c("year", "month")]
df <- merge(df, generic[,c("year", "month", "generic_cost")], by = c("year", "month"))
df[,new_cost:=cost + (generic_cost*volume_ratio)]
```

Which gives us:

```
df
   year month type cost volume volume_ratio generic_cost new_cost
1: 2020     1    A    1     10    0.1666667          600      101
2: 2020     1    B    3     20    0.3333333          600      203
3: 2020     1    C    5     30    0.5000000          600      305
4: 2020     2    A    2     11    0.1746032          630      112
5: 2020     2    B    4     21    0.3333333          630      214
6: 2020     2    C    6     31    0.4920635          630      316
```

This has a few extra columns, but new cost seems to be the most important column of interest.